# How to pass boolean property to class mediator in WSO2 EI

Tags: java, class, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Is there any way to pass a boolean parameter to the class mediator? I tried with the following code block.

```java
public class CustomMediator extends AbstractMediator {
    private String cacheEnabled;

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {}

    public String isCacheEnabled() {
        return cacheEnabled;
    }

    public void setCacheEnabled(String cacheEnabled) {
        this.cacheEnabled = cacheEnabled;
    }
}
```

```xml
<class name="lk.chathurabuddi.CustomMediator ">
    <property name="cacheEnabled" value="true"/>
</class>
```

But I'm getting the following runtime error.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-11 06:45:49,060] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.PropertyHelper} -  Error invoking setter method named : setCacheEnabled() that takes a single String, int, long, float, double or boolean parameterargument type mismatch {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.PropertyHelper}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a property mediator.

```
<class name="lk.chathurabuddi.CustomMediator">
 <property name="cacheEnabled" expression="$ctx:cacheEnabled"/>
</class>
```